# How to share a single Subject source

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to share a Subject source across multiple functions that filter their actions and do appropriate tasks, the ones that are not filtered should fall trough without modifications.

I've tried merging same source but it doesn't really work the way I need it to...

```
const source = new Subject()

source.next({ type: 'some type', action: {} })

merge(
  source,
  source.pipe(filter(...), do something),
  source.pipe(filter(...), do something),
  source.pipe(filter(...), do something),
  source.pipe(filter(...), do something),
).subscribe(...)
```

In this case I get original source + filtered ones.

I'm expecting to be able provide same source to multiple functions that can filter on types and do async behaviours, rest of the types that were not filtered should fall trough. Hope this is clear enough, or otherwise will try to make a better example. Thanks!

[example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-williamson-12owx)

Comment: Arey you using rxjs in any framework?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it with React

Comment: @David Can you please clarify your question? What is the meaning of "same source to multiple functions"? Did you mean sharing the subscription value? or do you want to reuse the code which filters the source i.e. `source.pipe(filter(...), do something)`

Comment: hey @user2216584, I've made an example. Please pay attention to the console where the pipe is being logged out. When you hit on action1 it will immediately log out the action and the same action after delay. The problem is that it should only log out after the delay and then other actions that do not need any work should fall trough, if that makes any sense? Thanks!

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-williamson-12owx

Comment: basically when you click on dispatch action 1 it should only dispatch after the delay, but other actions that do not have a filter on them should fall trough

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want one source with actions. Subject is fine way to do this.

Then you want to do some processing on each type of action. You can `filter` and `subscribe` to each substream.

```
const add$ = source.pipe(filter(a => a.type === "add")).subscribe(function onAddAction(a) {});
const remove$ = source.pipe(filter(a => a.type === "remove")).subscribe(function onRemove(a) {});
```

Or you can prepare substreams and then merge to all processed actions again.

```
const add$ = source.pipe(filter(a => a.type === "add"), tap(onAdd));
const remove$ = source.pipe(filter(a => a.type === "remove"), tap(onRemove));
const processedAction$ = merge(add$, remove$);
processedAction$.subscribe(logAction);
```

If you need to do some preprocessing on all actions you can use `share` or `shareReplay`. `toAction` will be called only once per each item.

```
const subject = new Subject();
const action$ = subject.pipe(map(toAction), share());
const add$ = action$.pipe(filter(isAdd));
...
merge(add$, remove$).subscribe(logAction);
```

And if you have problems splitting:

```
function not(predicate) {
    return function(item, ...args) {
        return !predicate(item, ...args);
    }

}

function any(...predicates) {
    return function(item, ...args) {
         return predicates.some(p => p(item, ...args));
    }
}

const a = source.pipe(filter(fa), map(doA));
const b = source.pipe(filter(fb), map(doB));
const c = source.pipe(filter(fc), map(doC));
const rest = source.pipe(filter(not(any(fa, fb, fc)));
merge(a, b, c, rest).subscribe(logAction);
```

Comment: Hello mate, thanks for your reply! This is exactly what I'm seeking for, I need to do some preprocessing on all actions. Unfortunately trying all sorts of variations from what you've provided did not get me anywhere. I've updated the example with scan reducer operator and and todos. If you click on add todo it will add it immediately and only then preprocessed action which is delayed. The problem is that share will log only one action, but what if that action has async behaviour, then it's completely ignored. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-williamson-12owx

Comment: maybe my whole approach is wrong here  but I don't see any other way of dispatching an action which is a single source of truth and next is available on Subject only. Then merging them all back together to the scan operator...

Comment: 1. `scan` may not be the best approach, because it is a reducer, and you want `map` and `filter` only
2. why do you keep merging _source$_ and _source$.pipe(filter(...))_? This will give you all the actions (_source$_) AND additionally some of them repeated. If you really want to `merge`, `merge` only filtered substreams.
3. You read _state_ returned by `useState()` once and then you try to mutate it - it is incorrect in React, you should react state each time to get a fresh one
4. You probably need to rethink this :-)

Comment: Did it help you?